# Capacitance and the battery connection

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

In the photo I added there is a question and its solution (given). It has been written at last(as I highlighted) that 'in order to get the minimum capacitance, dielectric should be removed and battery should be disconnected. I am able to understand the effect of capacitance on removing dielectric but unable get the effect of battery disconnection on the capacitance. Why is it necessary also to disconnect the battery to get the minimum capacitance when the dielectric is removed?

[image]

Comment: You should read it as two different statements/sentences. *Now the battery is disconnected,*  **and**  *the dielectric is removed so that the capacitance of the capacitor becomes a minimum.*

Comment: It's the removal of the dielectric that changes the capacitance, not disconnecting the battery.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Please transcribe text from images in your questions, so that those using assistive technologies can read it and search engines can properly index it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I am actually new here so I don't know several things. Can you help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: You can simply [edit] your question to type in the text that's currently in the screenshot.  To include equations, you can use MathJaX, which is a relative of LaTeX;  you can find [a tutorial on MathJaX here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it necessary also to disconnect the battery to get the minimum
> capacitance when the dielectric is removed?

Connecting or disconnecting the battery has no effect on the capacitance whereas removing the dielectric reduces the capacitance.

The purpose of disconnecting the battery is so the capacitor retains its maximum charge when the dielectric is removed. But the capacitor must be disconnected from the battery *before the dielectric is removed* so that the two criteria mentioned are met: Maximum charge plus minimum capacitance.
If the battery remains connected when the dielectric is removed some of the charge will be returned to the battery.

To clarify the steps involved the wording should probably be something like "Now battery is disconnected ***and then*** the dielectric is removed..."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will the charge remain same if the battery is disconnected but the dielectric is still there ?

Comment: @SaqibRashid Yes